# Is it possible to define "excludes" for check-static in uwsgi settings?

Tags: web-server, web-applications, uwsgi, static-routes, static-files

I have an application which I don't want to modify.

It has multiple directories with static files which are defined as static via `check-static` directive in uwsgi's .ini-file. My problem is that each request to `/api` endpoint checks all directories for static content with `lstat()` system call and it take.. a little time, really, just 0.0005 seconds per call, but aren't *zero* seconds sounds better?

It would be nice if all the static content would be accessed with `/static/` prefix in URL so I could replace `check-static` with `static-map` but I don't want to modify the application, any workaround is enough. If only uwsgi had option like:

```
check-static-exclude = /api
```

Maybe it is possible to achieve via uwsgi routing subsystem but I didn't find anything suitable in [docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InternalRouting.html).

Update: todo re-check routes `continue` action.

Comment: Put a web server in front of it to serve all static files.

Comment: At first I didn't think that communications between the servers (no matter via tcp or unix-sockets) would take less time than the static checks I'm trying to avoid, but then I've decided to re-check it. UNIX domain socket usually adds just 2 microseconds, so if the server for static can handle the request in less than 498 microseconds... it will do the trick! I will benchmark it on Monday and provide the details.

Comment: The checks have to happen somewhere. And this sounds like a premature micro-optimization.

Comment: Yeah, it have to, of course, except the `/api` endpoint. It's certainly have no static content inside and serves about 95% or even 99% of total requests. Development team put the task for refactoring of static serving aside until the autumn, so I'm trying to make a quick & easy _workaround_ to reduce I/O workload.